# php send email class - first attempt

Tags: php, oop, class, foreach

this is my first attempt of using php classes, never did it before, i'm quite enjoying the process.

**The code might be a bit messy, if you have any suggestions, i will appreciate very much!!**

About the problem, i'm trying to `echo "$asd->getData()"` and the outcome is a bit strange and i can't explain the result:

> Array ( [0] => nome [1] => email [2] => telemovel [3] => loja [4] =>
>   assunto [5] => mensagem [6] => localidade [7] => nserie [nome] =>
>   helder [email] => eeee [telemovel] => 913582837 [loja] => braga
>   [assunto] => [mensagem] => [localidade] => [nserie] => )

I was looking for the following result:

> Array([nome] => MyName [email] => emailHotmail [telemovel] =>
>   cellphone_here [loja] => store_name [assunto] => subject_here
>   [mensagem] => Message_here [localidade] => Location [nserie] =>
>   Serial_number)

Why are the array numbers/keys appearing?

```
<?php

class Email{

    private $data;

    function Email(){
            $this->data=array();
    }

        public function setData($d){
            $this->data = $d;
        }

    public function valida(){
            $verifica = true;
        foreach ($this->data as $campo) {
                $this->data[$campo] = $_GET[$campo];
                if(!isset($_GET[$campo]) || empty($_GET[$campo])){
                    $verifica=true;
                }
            }
            return $verifica;
    }

    public function getData(){
            print_r($this->data);
        }


        public function sendEmail($data){
            $to = ($this->data['loja']=="braga") ? "email1@email.com" : "email1@email.com";
            $subject = $this->data['assunto'];//$campos[4];
        $nserie = ($this->data['nserie']) ? '\r\n nº de série:'.$this->data['nserie'] : "";
        $localidade = ($this->data['localidade']) ? '\r\n Localidade:'.$this->data['localidade'] : "";
        $messages = $this->data['mensagem'];//$campos[5];
        $message = $messages.$nserie.$localidade;
            $message = htmlspecialchars_decode($message,ENT_QUOTES);//optional - I use encoding to POST data
            $name = $this->data['nome'];
            $from = $this->data['email'];//$campos[1];
            $headers = "From:".$name." <".$from.">\r\n";
            $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
            $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit";

            return mail($to, "=?utf-8?B?".base64_encode($subject)."?=", $message, $headers);
        }
}
$asd = new Email();
$campos = array('nome','email','telemovel','loja','assunto','mensagem','localidade','nserie');
$asd->setData($campos);
$asd->sendEmail($data);
echo ($asd->valida($data)) ? "sent<br/>" : "not sent<br/>";
echo "<br/>".$asd->getData()."<br/>";


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're printing out an array. You need to loop through and print out each item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$campos = array('nome','email','telemovel','loja','assunto','mensagem','localidade','nserie');
```

is the same as /short for

```
$campos = array(0=> 'nome',1=> 'email',....);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to set $campos in your call like this:

```
$campos = array('nome' => '','email' => '','telemovel' => '','loja' => '','assunto' => '','mensagem' => '','localidade' => '','nserie' => '');
$asd->setData($campos);
```

The $campos array was a list of values and you want to make those values keys of blank values instead.

Good luck!